# How to delete page after plugin deactivation

Tags: wordpress

I have created page when my plugin is activated. Its working fine. Now i want to delete the page when my plugin is deactivated.

My code is given below :

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_install_function');
function my_plugin_install_function() {
 $post = array('page_template' => '', 'comment_status' => 'closed', 'ping_status' =>  'closed' ,'post_author' => 1,'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),'post_name' => 'Checklists','post_status' => 'publish' ,
      'post_title' => 'Checklists',
      'post_type' => 'page',
);//insert page and save the id
$newvalue = wp_insert_post( $post, false );
//save the id in the database
update_option( 'hclpage', $newvalue ); }

 register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_remove' ); 
function my_plugin_remove() {//  the id of our page...
$the_page_id = get_option( $newvalue );
if( $the_page_id ) {

    wp_delete_post( $the_page_id ); // this will trash, not delete

}
```

How can I get the post id to delete the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wp_delete_post( $the_page_id, true );
```

The second parameter is to "force deletion", is boolean, and when set to `true` it deletes the post without trashing it.

You can read more in [the docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_post#Parameters)

You can get the ID using the `get_option` function:

```
get_option('hclpage');
```

Comment: you have to use the name of the option to get it from the DB.